# MySQL Error: #1054 - Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am having a strange error in mysql that despite of existing the column it generates and error saying that the column does not exists.

This is the table schema:

[image]

This is the Error in query:
[image]

Comment: I had that same error once when i had a reserved word as column. I dont think imagepath is a reserved word tho.... Try `AND user_ads.imagepath != 'NA'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to that table structure, edit the field.. there may b `space` before and after attribute name

Comment: Yes, Solved already. Actually there were spcaces before the field name. Thanks for you kind answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the column does not exist. Try to execute a 'desc user_ads' to check whether the column has indeed been removed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a dump of the database in order to see the data structure. For doing that you can use  the `mysqldump` command. Take a look at the ouput of this command.

Answer (score 0):

Should there be imagepath != 'NA' in mysql sql language? I would prefer <> 'NA'